# How to add server's ECDSA to known hosts but have a chance to verify it?

Tags: ssh

Is there any way to add known ECDSA fingerprint to known_hosts without trying to log into server or force ssh to show the key and ask me for acceptance?

When I'm trying to log-in for the first time, it just adds the key automatically without showing it which isn't very safe.

Comment: You have probably option `VerifyHostKeyDNS yes`, which verifies the host key with the SSHFP record in DNS and it doesn't bother you with manual checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of known_host is just the contents of the `.pub` file of the SSH host key, which (in the case of ECDSA) is found in `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`.

In most configurations, SSH should ask you for the host SSH key the first time around; if it doesn't, there are two possibilities:

1. You have `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `no`. If this is the case, SSH will just add any SSH key to `known_hosts`, without asking or performing any kind of check. To fix, set this option to `yes` (ssh won't ask, but will also refuse to connect to host with unknown key) or `ask` (ssh will ask what to do when confronted with an unknown key; the default)
2. The administrator of the SSH server has created an SSHFP DNS record for your server and has DNSSEC enabled, your SSH client is able to verify the DNSSEC chain, and the SSHFP fingerprint matches the one your server exports. In this case, the SSH fingerprint *is* verified, just not through the regular means, and SSH won't bother you with the minutiae of checking that everything is okay.

Comment: I put "StrictHostKeyChecking ask" into /etc/ssh/ssh_config but nothing changed. It still accepts fingerprint without showing it nor asking. Also I don't have any user-specific configuration file in my ~/.ssh. Strange

Comment: It is even more strange: when I call ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=ask <hostname> it still doesn't ask for anything

Comment: Did you check for sshfp dns records? Maybe clear out your .ssh/authorized_keys and try again with `-v`; if it does find something in dns, that will tell you.

Comment: Ok - I know what is going on. I removed it with ssh-keygen -R by IP and it is necessary to remove it by dns.name as well. Thanks!